# iOS -- fprintf logs are not getting printed on Xcode Organizer Console

Tags: ios, c, xcode

`fprintf` logs are not getting printed on Xcode Organizer Console.

I also tried with

```
fprintf(stdout, "STARTED!\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

and

```
printf("");
```

but none of the above seems to be working. I can see the logs in Xcode Debug Console but not in Organizer Console.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using `NSLog` instead?

Comment: @devnull `NSLog()` prints to standard error, `printf()` prints to standard output -- I guess both are supposed to appear (at least both do appear for me when I run a program).

Comment: I have to use statements in .cpp library class. I can't use NSLog in that

Comment: What Organizer Console are you referring to?

Comment: in xCode -> Press Cmd + Shift + 2. It will open up Organizer. You can see attached devices in that. Click on device and select Console Option

Comment: I don't do enough iOS development to know if that should work or not, however I always use a proper log class / function, that writes to a file.  That file is then useful in production as well as development.

Answer (score 2):

Use `syslog` thus:

```
#include <syslog.h>
syslog(LOG_ERR, "Started!");
```

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/syslog.3.html